# Javascript variables not updated after Angularjs ng-repeat changes made to DOM

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

I have an angular app which extracts data from a `JSON` file which populates the webpage via directive template for the user using `ng-repeat`.

When the page is initially loaded, the ID(from the json file) in (p) element is 1.

```
<p id="pollidholder" style ="display:none" ng-bind-html="item.id">{{item.id}}</p>
```

Once the user presses a button(Next, ng-click), the ID is updated 2 in the `<p>` element via a directive template. I am using the ID to register the users input.

In my back end Javascript (uservotedd.js), I am using

```
var pollidholder1 = document.getElementById('pollidholder').innerHTML;
```

to extract the ID from the `<p>` element.

However, the ID is not updated from 1 to 2 for the var pollidholder even though the `<p>` element is changed on the page itself.

How do I update my Javascript variable once the html `<p>` element has changed? Please help. I would like avoid major rewrite of my code. Note the Alert message is not update to reflect the change in ID when the user hits the submit button.

Please find the plunker example here https://embed.plnkr.co/3kIxhW2Iq5lKQm81csln/

Comment: Problem statement not cleared !!

Comment: Why do you need to use `getElementById().innerHTML` when you already have the data in `item` accessible? Please provide a [mcve] and take a few minutes to read through [ask]

Comment: I have added the plunker example in original post above

Comment: @RohitJindal Please review again

Comment: @charlietfl - How would I access item.id in my Javascript script? I have uploaded an example to plunker

Comment: for starters you need to look at errors thrown in browser console. That plunker demo has syntax and dependency errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just don't use `onclick` in your html here:

```
<div class="simple-button" onlclick="idchange()" ng-click="change()" style ="font-size: 4vw ">Next</div>
```

Put all the code of `idchange` into the `change` function of the controller, and you will have access to all the variables you need. For example:

```
$scope.change = function() {
    $scope.indexToShow = ($scope.indexToShow + 1) % $scope.items.length;
    alert($scope.items[$scope.indexToShow].id);
}
```

Don't try to dodge angular's encapsulation, using `onclick` rather than `ng-click` will cause lots of confusion for beginners. Just use `ng-click` and you will be fine.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I needed. I put var pollidholder1 in my app.js and reused it in my javascript uservotedd.js. It worked like a charm. Thanks again